# XML character entities not parsing

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, html-entities, xml-entities

I'm working with a server.xml file...

### Case 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Resource name="${app.name}" />
```

In `catalina.properties` i have declared the `app.name`

```
app.name=&#x6F;&#x72;
```

### Case 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Resource name="&#x6F;&#x72;" />
```

The problem is why case 2 is working and case 1 not?
Why in case 1 XML entities not parsing?

I.e the output is :

```
<Resource name= "&#x6F;&#x72;"  />    //in case 1
<Resource name= "or"  />              //in case 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Key point:**  Entity expansion happens *during XML parsing.*

### Case 1

In case 1, during parsing, there are no entities in `Resources/@name` – just `${app.name}`, which the program calling the XML parser would presumably go on to substitute the literal text, `&#x6F;&#x72;`, for the variable:

```
<Resource name="&#x6F;&#x72;" />
```

Downstream processing likely doesn't know how to deal with `&#x6F;&#x72;`, and you have your "not working" case.

### Case 2

In case 2, `&#x6F;&#x72;` exists in the XML file prior to parsing.  After parsing, effectively, the program calling the XML parser sees the entities expanded:

```
<Resource name="or" />
```

and is able to "work" because it knows what to do when `@name` is `"or"`.

Note that had `catalina.properties` been an XML file, the expansion would have occurred then *that* file was parsed, and you'd be back to your "working" case.

### Solution

Options include one of the following:

1. Hardwire the entities in `server.xml` rather than in `catalina.properties`.
2. Force the property substitution to happen prior to XML parsing of `server.xml`.
3. Use Unicode characters directly (not encoded as XML entities) in your  `catalina.properties` file.